# I can't locate elements in an HTML page with xpath or CSS Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried much times copying the **xpath** of an element, it fails to give me like this xpath below:

```
//*[@id="search_form_input_homepage"]
```

It gives me instead such as the following:

```
/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input
```

I even tried with locating the element with CSS class and name, but whenever I submit the code with **Python**, I still get this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input
```

Here are the HTML elements I want to find their xpath:

```
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">

<input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are copying the Xpath or the full Xpath? I only get strings similar to `/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input` when I copy full Xpath.

Comment: I only get 'Copy Xpath', the 'Copy full XPath' is unavailable

Comment: Yes, do 'Copy Xpath'